# Replace value from database with the structure of a contenteditable div

Tags: php, html, database, contenteditable

I'm printing a value of a mysql field on a `contenteditable div` and I need it to adopt the structure corresponding to it. With the same `divs` and line breaks `br`.

I have tried the `nl2br` function of `php` but it only generates line breaks `br`, so it does not work well for me. I need the complete structure.

For example:

```php
<div id="textbox" contenteditable="true"><?php echo nl2br($text); ?></div>
```

Where `$text` is a text with line breaks `\n` from database.

So when executing `nl2br`, change them all by `br`.

I currently get this:

```html
<div id="textbox" contenteditable="true">
  Line 1
  <br>
  Line 2
  <br>
  <br>
  Line 3
</div>
```

And I need to get this:

```html
<div id="textbox" contenteditable="true">
  Line 1
  <div>Line 2</div>
  <div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>Line 3</div>
</div>
```

Which is what is generated automatically when writing on a `contenteditable div`.

Comment: What does the original `$text` look like and how do you know what should be enclosed in `<div>` tags?

Comment: @NigelRen In the database it is saved with `\n` (they are not visible but they are really there). The structure of the `conteneditable div` I know it is that inspecting it having written something inside.

Comment: @NigelRen Try writing something in a `contententeditable div`, inspect the element and you will see that structure of `divs` and `brs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick attempt at what your after, output looks OK, but make sure it works for what your after.

The idea is to just split the text into lines - start off with the first line of text as is, then add each subsequent line in `<div>` tags - if the line is blank - then set it to `<br />`...

```
$text = 'Line 1
Line 2

Line 3';

$lines = explode("\n",$text);
$output = array_shift($lines);
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $output .= "<div>".($line?:"<br />")."</div>";
}

echo $output;
```

With the sample above this gives...

```
Line 1<div>Line 2</div><div><br /></div><div>Line 3</div>
```

Comment: Cool! I've been doing tests and it seems to work as expected. Thank you very much for your help!